# setState to update an interface array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need to update an array of address inside the User interface. I am trying to use setState to update the address from UI form. I have tried the following:

```
setUser({...user, address: [...(user?.address|| []), addressObject]});
```

However I am getting the following error: Type 'Address | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Address'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Address'.

```
export default interface User{

    firstName: string,
    surName: string,
    email: string,
    phone: string
    Address: Address[]
}
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: what is `addressObject`?

Comment: Unrelated, but `Address` isn't a great name for a collection of addresses, and the `setUser` call is using a property of `address` while the interface spells it `Address`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `address` prop is defined before you set it to the state. You can do that in the following fashion:

```js
if (user.address){
    setUser({...user, address: [...(user.address|| []), addressObject]});
}
```

ts will pick up that `user.address` will be defined by the time the `setState` is being called.

OR, if you want to allow `address` to be undefined, then you can change the interface definition to:

```js
export default interface User{
    ...
    Address: Address[] | undefined
}
```